# Transform vector array in C++ Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen

Getting started in the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) math library, I'm having trouble with a very simple task: transform a series of vectors using a quaternion. Seems everything I do results in no `operator*` found, or mixing an array with a matrix.

```
Eigen::Quaternionf rot = …;
Eigen::Array3Xf series = …;

// expected this to work as matrix() returns a Transformation:
series.matrix().colwise() *= rot.matrix();

// expected these to work as it's standard notation:
series = rot.matrix() * series.matrix().colwise();
series = rot.toRotationMatrix() * series.matrix().colwise();

// Also tried adding .homogeneous() as one example used it… no dice
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm... not sure why you use an Array in your example. I guess you want to transform m 3-vectors by rot, right? You could use a 3xm Matrix for this.

How about

```
using namespace Eigen;
Quaternionf rot = ...;
Matrix<float,3,Dynamic> series = ...;

series = rot.toRotationMatrix() * series;
```

Comment: Thanks! `Array` was convenient for some vector-scalar additions not shown in the example. But `Array` is wrong, the object really is a matrix. Setting its type as such and calling `.array()` instead of `.matrix()` fixed the issue. It is odd that the return from `.matrix()` didn't work the same way… but whatever.

Comment: I just realised I meant to use `.toRotationMatrix()` instead of `.matrix()`. I don't think Arrays are required here. I've edited the original answer.

Comment: I think `series *= rot;` suffices… it looks like my code uses an implicit conversion from `Quaternionf` to `Matrix3f`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very blunt, but effective solution:

```
for (int vector = 0; vector < series.cols(); ++vector)
   series.col(vector) = rot * series.col(vector).matrix();
```

The point here is that somewhere, someone has to read your code. A simple `for` loop is often easiest to understand.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I don't find that easier to read than the things I tried first.